# PHP move file using part of a known file name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a directory full of images (40,000 +) that I need sorted. I have designed a script to sort them into knew proper directories, however, I am having issues with the file name.

The images urls with the id they belong to are stored in a database, and I am using the database in conjunction with the script to sort the images.

My Problem:

The image url's in the database are shortened. An example of such corresponding images are like this:

```
dsc_0107-367.jpg
dsc_0107-367-5478-2354-0014.jpg
```

The first part of the filenames are the same, but the actual file contains more info. I'd like a way to move the file from the database with the known part of the file name.

I have a basic code:

```
<?php

$sfiles = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM files WHERE gal_id = '$_GET[id']");

while($file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sfiles)){

$folder = $file['gal_id'];
$fileToMove = $file['filename'];

$origDir = "mypath/to/dir";

$newDir = "mypath/to/new/dir/$file['gal_id']";

mkdir "$newDir";

mv "$fileToMove" "$newDir";

}
```

Im just confused on how to select the file based on the small part from the database.

NOTE: It's not as simple as changing the number of chars in the db, because the db was given to me from an external site thats been deleted. So this is all the data I have.

Comment: SQL column have a length property which you need to be aware. Set a bigger length instead of 12.

Comment: Well start writing something and if you get problems we will gladly help you out. However **SO != Get your free coders here**

Comment: I have updated my code. Im not looking for Get A Free Coder. Im more than happy to write code. Im looking for how to select and move part of the file with the 12 chars I know of the longer filename. @RiggsFolly

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: The code in this question is really not solving the problem of how to match up a partial filename, plus you haven't given more than one very trivial example on how this plays out.

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand your last comment. The code I provided so far is what I got to move the file to the new directory. Im looking for guidence on how how to match the partial so I rectify my code to solve the problem. Am I understanding your comment correctly? @tadman

Comment: Have a poke at the [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function and see how far you get.

Comment: Thanks. Im reading up on it now. @tadman

Comment: I think I understand that. I am working on it now and will update you. @tadman

Comment: I tried that and it's not returning results because theres nothing that matches my file. Example: dsc_001.jpg because in the directory its actually dsc_001_002.jpg. Having the jpg there is causing there to be no matches. If I could overcome that, I think we have a solution. @tadman

Comment: Rewrite your filename to `dsc_001*.jpg` and try again.

Comment: the only thing that get outputted is array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP can open files using the function `glob()` . Glob searches your server, or specified directory, for any files containing a "match" to a pattern you specify.

Using `glob()` like this will pull your images from a partial name.

1. Run this query separate from the second:

   ```
   $update = mysqli($dbconn, "UPDATE files 
             SET filename = REPLACE(filename, '.info', ''));
   ```

`filename` should be the column in your database that contains the list of images. The reason we are removing the .jpg from the db columns is if your names are partial, the .jpg may not match with the given name in your directory. With it removed, we can search solely for the pattern of the name.

2. Build the query to select and move the folders:

   ```
    $sfiles = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM files");

    while($file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sfiles)){

    $fileToMove = $file['filename'];

    // because glob outputs the result set into an array, 
    // we will use foreach to run each result from the array individually.

    foreach(glob("$fileToMove*") as filename){

    echo "$filename <br>"; 
    // I'm echoing this out to see that the results are being run 
    // one line at a time and to confirm the photo's are 
    // matching the pattern.

    $folder = $file['gal_id']; 
    // pulling the id from the db of the gallery the photo belongs to. 
    // This will specify which folder to move the pic to. 
    // Replace gal_id with the name of your column.

    $newDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/wysiwyg/kcfinder/upload/images/gallery/old/".$folder;

    copy($filename,$newDir."/".$filename); 
    // I would recommend copy rather than move. 
    // This will leave the original photo in its place. 
    // This measure is to ensure the photo made it to the new directory so you don't lose it.
    //  You could go back and delete the photos after if you'd prefer.

        }


    }
   ```

Comment: Sorry about the code. I don't know why it didn't place it in a code format.

Comment: Bullet points [no.1., no.2.]  (even if they're not HTML formatted as bullets), make the code require 8 spaces rather than 4 to become a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL query is ripe for SQL Injection, and your GET statement needs to be sanitized, if I went to your page with something similar to :

```
pagename.php?id=' DROP TABLE; #--
```

this is going to end extremely badly for you.

So;

OVerall it's much better to use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). THere's LOTS and LOTS of data about how to use them all over SO and the wider internet. What I show below is ***only*** a stopgap measure.

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id']  //This forces the id value to be numeric.
$sfiles = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM files WHERE gal_id = ".$id);
```

Also keep note of closing your `'` and `"` quotes as your original doesn't close the array key wrapper quotes.

I never used `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and always used `mysqli_fetch_array` so will use that as it fits the same syntax :

```
while($file = mysqli_fetch_array($sfiles)){
     $folder = $id //same thing. 
     $fileToMove = $file['filename'];
     $origDir = "mypath/to/dir/".$fileToMove;
     //This directory shold always start with Server['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 
     //Please read the manual for it. 
     $newDir =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mypath/to/new/dir/".$folder;

     if(!is_dir($newDir)){
     mkdir $newDir;
     }

    // Now the magic happens, copies the file to the new directory.
    // Then (optionally) delete the original. 
    copy($origDir,$newDir."/".$fileToMove);
    unlink($origDir); //removes original.

    // Add a flag to your Database to know that this file has been copied, 
    // ideally you should resave the filepath to the correct new one. 
    //MySQL update saving the new filepath. 
    }
```

Read up on [PHP Copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) and [PHP unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

## And; please use Prepared Statements for PHP and Database interactions.!

Comment: I only have the first 12 characters of the file name. Will this still move the file given that circumstance?

Comment: This answer does not answer the question of moving files with a partial file name match. @Martin